# pdo execute multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to run an insert and a simultaneous update, but I'm using only insert test to catch errors.
The PDO does not report the error when I define a correct and an incorrect table, but if I run a query to select one incorrect table the error is reported.
I do not have enough knowledge to solve this problem, i really need to execute two queries together
Thank you.

```
$db-> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

try{
    $stmt = $db-> prepare( "INSERT INTO test ( name ) values( 'new name' );
                            INSERT INTO xast ( xame ) values( 'new name' );" );
    $stmt->execute();
}catch( PDOException $e ){
    print_r( $e );
}


try{
    $stmt = $db-> prepare( "INSERT INTO xast ( xame ) values( 'new name' );" );
    $stmt->execute();
}catch( PDOException $e ){
    print_r( $e );
}
**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'xame'**
```

Comment: Do you get an error if you do multiple queries and the error is in the first one?

Comment: the correct field is `name` and `I switched to `xame` to catch the error, but he did not shoot.

Comment: I understand, my question is whether putting the bad one first instead of second makes a difference.

Comment: As far as I can tell, executing multiple statements is not officially supported in PDO. There's nothing about it in the PDO manual. mysqli has support for them, can you use that instead? You mentioned it in your tags.

Comment: yes, can try with mysqli. Do you have a tutorial for me? thank you

Comment: It's in the documentation at php.net.

Comment: I tryed with multi_query and happened exactly the same thing: **insert correct and insert wrong** : entered the first record and not returned error

Comment: Did you use `mysqli_next_result()` like it says in the `multi_query()` documentation?

Comment: only multi_query (), I will read the other now, thanks

Comment: there is no reason to run 2 queries in a single call. it's ok to make it in 2 separate calls.

Comment: There multi_query() and i need to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no point in preparing multiple queries in your case.

First, prepared statements invented especially for tins case: prepare once, execute many. So, you can prepare this way

```
INSERT INTO test (name) values(?)
```

and then execute as many times as many inserts you have

Next. For the INSERT query Mysql supports multiple VALUES clause in one query, like

```
INSERT INTO test (name) values ('new name' ),('name'),(...)
```

and so on.

If you need to update after insert - no problem too.
Just run 2 separate queries - one INSERT and one UPDATE. There will be not a single problem.

Comment: I said I need to insert and update, not an insert with many fields. i need insert and an update, but apparently not working correctly, thank you